# Downgrade tar package to particalar version

Tags: ubuntu

Dears,

Under Ubuntu/Linux I want to downgrade "tar" package from 1.27-1 version to 1.26ver.

per apt-cache showpkg tar I have:

```
Package: tar
Versions: 
1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz) (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz
                  MD5: 48033bf96442788d1f697785773ad9bb

1.27.1-1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz
                  MD5: 48033bf96442788d1f697785773ad9bb


Reverse Depends: 
  dpkg,tar 1.23
  dpkg,tar 1.23
  vfu,tar 1.20-1
  pristine-tar,tar 1.27-3
  patool,tar 1.26
  dump,tar 1.13.92-3
  amanda-common,tar 1.12
  dpkg,tar 1.23
  backuppc,tar 1.13
Dependencies: 
1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1 - libacl1 (2 2.2.51-8) libc6 (2 2.17) libselinux1 (2 1.32) bzip2 (0 (null)) ncompress (0 (null)) xz-utils (0 (null)) tar-scripts (0 (null)) cpio (1 2.4.2-38) dpkg-dev (3 1.14.26) cpio (3 2.4.2-39) 
1.27.1-1 - libacl1 (2 2.2.51-8) libc6 (2 2.17) libselinux1 (2 1.32) bzip2 (0 (null)) ncompress (0 (null)) xz-utils (0 (null)) tar-scripts (0 (null)) cpio (1 2.4.2-38) dpkg-dev (3 1.14.26) cpio (3 2.4.2-39) 
Provides: 
1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1 - 
1.27.1-1 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

I do this

```
apt-get install tar=1.26
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.26' for 'tar' was not found
```

I need to help on correct way to downgrade particular package. Per Ubuntu documentation:

sudo apt-get install [packagename]=[version]

I have specified version which I want to downgrade to 1.26.
How to correctly downgrade to specified version?

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tar for the available versions of tar for your distribution. You will find a tar 2.16 version at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tar_1.26-4ubuntu1.1_i386.deb or https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tar_1.26-4ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb depending on your architecture.

Download the .deb file and try to install it with `sudo dpkg install`

I hope you won't have problems with unsatisfied dependencies.